# Plot Bar Chart in R - Year issue

Tags: r, shiny

I'm working with an shinyapp that creates bar charts according to some user input. Let's say that the user has selected this `df`

```
type;year
a;2001
b;2001
a;2002
b;2006
a;2007
b;2007
```

when i plot the data, it won't show the years `2003`to `2005`, of course, Because it has no values. So, if i plot them, there will be no gap between these years and it will look wrong.

Any ideas how to set the x-axis value even if it has no data in it?

I've tried to look for something similiar but couldn't find it.

Comment: a reproducible example would help....also Is year a factor or numerical value?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to wrap `year` column with `as.numeric`

```
library(ggplot2)

#sample plot
ggplot(df, aes(x = as.numeric(year), fill = type)) +
  geom_bar()
```

**Output plot is**
[image]

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(type = c("a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b"), year = c("2001", 
"2001", "2002", "2006", "2007", "2007")), .Names = c("type", 
"year"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```